# write into popup

Tags: abap

I have to display a popup for a legend like in STMS transaction [image]

I know how to write this tab with WRITE statement,  but how can I display it in a popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `CALL SCREEN ... STARTING AT ...`, then using `SUPPRESS DIALOG` in the PBO processing to bypass the screen (dynpro) processor. Then, in the PAI processing, use `LEAVE TO LIST-PROCESSING` followed by the `WRITE` statements. You can follow this in the function module `TMS_UI_POPUP_LEGENDE` that shows the popup you mentioned as a reference. The procedure is [documented in the online help](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/9f/db9d2f35c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm) as well.

---

In an ABAP dialog application, you're either working with [screens](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/e4/2adbef449911d1949c0000e8353423/content.htm) or with (interactive) [lists](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/e4/2adbe9449911d1949c0000e8353423/content.htm). To get a popup window, you have to create and `CALL` a custom screen (dynpro). Inside that screen, you hand over control to the list processor. That's the component responsible for taking what ever you `WRITE` and place it somewhere on the screen. For some - probably mostly historical - reason, the command to do so is `LEAVE TO LIST-PROCESSING`. I suppose that at some point, the intended flow between screens and lists was different from what it has become today, and that was the reason for naming the command this way. From a modern point of view and especially in your use case, the `LEAVE` aspect does not make any sense, so just take it as it is and use it.

Also note that it's `LEAVE`**`TO`**`LIST PROCESSING` - `LEAVE LIST-PROCESSING` without `TO` is the opposite statement!

Comment: Thanks Volker, i Knew that you are always present to give a good answer on a abap questions, I check that and i'll accept your answer.

Comment: Excuse me Volker, can you explain me what is the leave list-processing?

Comment: Yes but i want that this display in dialog and this display like normal screen ???

Comment: Did you use the `STARTING AT` portion of `CALL SCREEN`?

Comment: You have right i forgot it. But when i make like you wrote, i have first scree empty ansd when i do F3 or back function leave to screen 0 i have my tab. Why

Comment: Because I messed up the answer - you need `SUPPRESS DIALOG` in the PBO and the `LEAVE...` stuff in the PAI processing. It's been a long time since I've actually used this - I tend to avoid (interactive) lists wherever possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67567/discussion-between-shmoolki-and-vwegert).